# Не работает selectNodes VB6

Tags: xml, vb6

Всем привет,
Не получается распарсить domdocument60. Обычный domdocument и domdocument30 работает стандартно. Конкретно не работает метод selectNodes().
Пример кода:

```
    Info.selectNodes("//*/CorporationTrustability").item(0)
```

Данный запрос выдает пустой результат (length = 0), ну и соответственно ругается.
Переустановил уже xmlparser 6, нифига не помогло, может кто сталкивался?
Язык VB6, Windows XP. К сожалению, воспользоваться domdocument30 или domdocument невозможно, так как на сервере, где крутится задача, они не поддерживаются...

Comment: Изменения в самом запросе никаких результатов не дают, работает только звездочка. При этом поиск по атрибутам пашет и можно выбрать в childnodes

Answer (score 1):

Нашел проблему. Дело было в том, что с xml версия 6 сменился аттрибут SelectionLanguage (было XSLPattern, стало XPath). Поэтому такой же запрос теперь будет выглядеть примерно

```
  GetInfoAboutCompany.selectNodes("//*[contains(name(),'СвНаимЮЛ')]")
```